# Error approximation of Simpson's rule

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

My calculus book states that the error of the Simpson's formula is equal to
$$\frac{(b-a)^5 f^{(4)}(c)}{2880n^4}$$
for a $c \in [a, b]$, if the function has a continuous fourth derivative.

Is this for any $c$ in the interval, or just a unique one? If its for a specific one, how would I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c here is a specific value in the interval. This comes from the Mean Value Theorem.
As for finding the value, you cannot find the exact value. This is an error term, which you basically need for obtaining a range and cannot give you the exact value.