# Error bound in Simpson's formula

Tags: numerical-methods

[image: Calculated inegral with Simpson's formula but without usage of error bound information]
I have and extra information that error has to be smaller than $10^{-2}$ , is there any formula for error bounds that I could use for different types of functions?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728761/error-approximation-of-simpsons-rule?rq=1 may help

Comment: Take also care what $n$ actually means, in the link it is the number of Simpson segments, each having a midpoint, not the total number of segments like in your calculation. If you compute $S_2$ and $S_8$ and from them the error estimate, your task might actually already be solved.